# Is there a tool for analyzing what a bash script does line by line?

Tags: bash

I need to understand few bash scripts from time to time, but I'm not a bash expert and I'd like to learn it during reading each script. Is there a tool which can tell me what each script line does?

for example, it can tell me what each line does, and through what grammar

```
GPU_ID=$1
NET=$2
NET_lc=${NET,,}
DATASET=$3
```

for now I'm searching google by keywords "bash ${var,,}", but the search engine isn't smart enough to give me any thing useful, I can't find even the correct naming of this grammar.

Please don't tell me that asking on StackOverflow is my best option for all such kind of beginner's questions.

Comment: This is a kind of tool that I'd like to have for every language I'm learning, but I've never seen it for any of them. It's probably partly caused by the vast scope of such a program, having to be correct and useful to basically any level programmer without being enormously verbose

Comment: did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run your script using `-x` and see what's happening after each line, for example

```
$ bash -x script.sh A B
+ GPU_ID=A
+ NET=B
+ NET_lc=b
+ DATASET=
```

If you want to know what `${var,,}` is (or anything else), just check `man bash`

```
   ${parameter^pattern}
   ${parameter^^pattern}
   ${parameter,pattern}
   ${parameter,,pattern}
          Case  modification.   This expansion modifies the case of alpha‐
          betic characters in parameter.
          ...
```

Comment: May also want to let him know he can `set -x` on the 1st line after the `#!/bin/bash` shebang within a script.

Comment: This is a really useful/wonderful trick! Thank you a lot !